# Flexbox wrapped content and resizing

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox container with 4 elements.

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

I want to position items within like this:

```
┌────────────────────┬────────┐
│ FIRST item has     │ SECOND │
│ longer multi-line  │        │
│ text content       │        │
├────────────────────┴────────┤
│ THIRD                       │
├─────────────────────────────┤
│ FOURTH                      │
└─────────────────────────────┘
```

So for 3<sup>rd</sup> an 4<sup>th</sup> it's rather easy by setting their `flex-basis: 100%` and that's fine.

I've got a problem with 1<sup>st</sup> and 2<sup>nd</sup> item.

1. 1<sup>st</sup> item has quite a bit of content so it should wrap when it can't fit a single line
2. 2<sup>nd</sup> item should have non-wrapped text and should take as much horizontal space as needed by its content.
3. 1<sup>st</sup> space should take all remaining space.

### The problem

I can't seem to make it work with `flex-basis` and `flex-grow`. If I set only the 1<sup>st</sup> to grow and not constrain it in width it will wrap the 2<sup>nd</sup> item into the next line. But if I do constrain it, then these wdth constrants can't really be flexible according to 2<sup>nd</sup> item's width which adjusts to its content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can set:

1. `white-space: nowrap` and `flex: 0 1 auto` for the second div,
2. `flex: 1` for the first div

See demo below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container > div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.container div:nth-child(1) {
  flex:1;
}
.container div:nth-child(2) {
  white-space: nowrap;
  flex:0 1 auto;
}
.container div:nth-child(3),
.container div:nth-child(4) {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>FIRST itema has
    <br/>longer multiline longer multiline longer multiline longer multiline longer multiline longer multiline longer multiline 
    <br/>text content</div>
  <div>Some text content here and some more</div>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <div>Some text here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works. I didn't think I'd have to set shrink as well. I don't really get it yet will have to dig a bit deeper to completely understand **why** it works.